# Build & Refresh every time when ever I Change code of Compose Jatpack

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working `Compose Jetpack` and try to learn new staff but I'm facing irritating thing

When ever I Change code of compose jectpack code android design screen show me

> The preview is out of date Build & Refresh

**Is there any way here no need Build & Refresh layout**

[image]

Comment: What do you want exactly? If you do not build, how will the device know what changes have been made?

Answer (score -1):

It is compulsory to build and refresh in order to see the preview. It is similar to deploying app on the device. Building is necessary to convert your code to machine readable data which is how it renders your stuff on the screen

Comment: this is so time taking compare to .xml layout

Comment: Yes it is, but try to decrease build duration by following the official guide. It will help

Comment: Anyway, I think your question's been answered. If you want any other performance related help, start a new thread